# How to use sticky broadcasts to perform a task when app comes back into foreground ?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

My app uses internet connection to load data from a web server. So I have a BroadcastReceiver which keeps checking for internet connection availability and shows a persistent AlertDialog if connection is lost. Its working fine. My BroadcastReceiver is declared in manifest.

```
 <receiver android:name="com.project.service.ConnectivityChangedReceiver"
      android:label="NetworkConnection">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
      </intent-filter> 
 </receiver>
```

Now the problem is that I show this AlertDialog only when my app is in foreground. So if user is in another app and internet is lost, my AlertDialog won't show(though the Broadcast event was fired). And now if user comes to my app , the Dialog does not show up because event was already fired once. But I want it to show up because I don't want user to be able to do anything until connection is recovered.

I read somewhere that we can use Sticky Broadcasts for this purpose but I don't know how and where to use them. Please help.

Comment: I think,you should use service instead of broadcast